# How do I reference a WPF menu item dynamically in VB.net

Tags: wpf, vb.net, menuitem

How do I reference a WPF menu item dynamically in VB.net

I have a menu in my Application.xaml inside my main window template (see XAML code below).  In all my other windows I “invoke” this template by setting the window’s style = “(DynamicResource WindowTemplateMain}”.  What I want to be able to do is to dynamically set the “isEnabled” property of each menu item based on their access privileges.  I can get all the privileges and loop through them just fine.  My problem, being fairly new to WPF, is how to I reference any given menu item so I can change the “isEnabled” property?

For example, in my menu below, let’s say I want to disable the menu item “mnu_TimeEntry”.  How do I reference “mnu_TimeEntry” in order to change the “isEnabled” property to false?  I need the vb code that will do this.  Or should I be handling the main menu an entirely different way?

Thanks in advance for your help.  Here is all the relevant code:

Application.xaml (where I create the menu):

```xaml
    <!--Global Window Template-->
    <Style x:Key="WindowTemplateMain" TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
                    <DockPanel Margin="0,0,-1.667,0.333" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto">
                        <DockPanel.Background>
                            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" MappingMode="RelativeToBoundingBox" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                <GradientStop Color="{StaticResource mwb_WindowBackgroundGradient0}" Offset="0"/>
                                <GradientStop Color="{StaticResource mwb_WindowBackgroundGradient1}" Offset="1"/>
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </DockPanel.Background>
                        <Menu x:Name="MWB_MainMenu" DockPanel.Dock="Top"  IsMainMenu="True">
                            <MenuItem Header="_File">
                                <MenuItem Header="_Time Entry" Name="mnu_TimeEntry" Click="mnu_TimeEntryClick" />
                                <Separator />
                                <MenuItem Header="_Logout" Click="mnu_LogoutClick"/>
                                <Separator />
                                <MenuItem Header="_Exit" Click="mnu_ExitClick"/>
                            </MenuItem>
                            <MenuItem Header="_Reports">
                                <MenuItem Header="_Report1" />
                                <MenuItem Header="_Report2" />
                                <MenuItem Header="_Report3" />
                            </MenuItem>
                            <MenuItem Header="_Administration">
                                <MenuItem Header="_Clients" Click="mnu_ClientsClick" />
                                <MenuItem Header="Contac_ts" Click="mnu_ContactsClick" />
                                <MenuItem Header="System _Maintenance">
                                    <MenuItem Header="User Access _Group Maintenance" Click="mnu_UserGroupMaintClick"/>
                                    <MenuItem Header="System _Window Maintenance" Click="mnu_SysWinMaintClick"/>
                                </MenuItem>
                            </MenuItem>
                            <MenuItem Header="_Test Window" Click="mnu_TestWindow"/>
                        </Menu>
                        <Grid Margin="0,0,0,0" Width="Auto">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="790*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="3*"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"/>
                            <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource mwb_Copyright}" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="5,0,4.666,4" />
                        </Grid>
                    </DockPanel>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Sample Window.xaml (where I set the style to the window template and from which in the .vb code I want to reference the menu item “mnu_TimeEntry”):

```xaml
<Window x:Name="MWB_TimeKeeper_Time_Entry" x:Class="MWB_TimeKeeper_Time_Entry"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MWB_TimeKeeper"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MWB TimeKeeper - Time Entry"
    Style="{DynamicResource WindowTemplateMain}" Width="800" Height="600">
.
.
.
</Window>
```

vb code that obviously doesn't work but shows the concept of what I want to do:

```vb
Private Sub MWB_TimeKeeper_Time_Entry_Loaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Loaded, MyBase.Loaded

    mnu_TimeEntry.IsEnabled = False

End Sub
```

"mnu_TimeEntry" in this case throws an error because it is not declared.  I can declare it as a menuitem but still don't know how to link it to the action menu item from the WPF menu.

Thanks again to anyone who can help this new WPF programmer.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should define a contract for what a user is able to do and so on, then map your UI elements to some `Boolean` :

**Code**

```
Class MainWindow
    Private Sub FrameworkElement_OnLoaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles Me.Loaded
        Dim workspace As New Workspace
        workspace.User = New DefaultUser()
        DataContext = workspace
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Workspace
    Public Property User() As IUser

    Public ReadOnly Property Text() As String
        Get
            Return "Hello, world !"
        End Get
    End Property

End Class

Public Interface IUser
    ReadOnly Property CanEdit() As Boolean
End Interface

Public NotInheritable Class DefaultUser
    Implements IUser

    Public ReadOnly Property CanEdit As Boolean Implements IUser.CanEdit
        Get
            Return False
        End Get
    End Property

End Class
```

**XAML**

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication5"
        mc:Ignorable="d" d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance local:Workspace}"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Menu >
            <MenuItem DataContext="{Binding Path=User}" Header="_Edit" IsEnabled="{Binding CanEdit}" />
        </Menu>

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Text}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Result**

[image]

So basically you invert things, instead of referencing menu items, these would either query whether current user has this right and be enabled accordingly.

Comment: I appreciate your answer.  While it doesn't solve (that I could make work) my problem since my menu is in a global style template, it did make me rethink how I was doing things and the need to perhaps move the menu out of the style template and just use the main window to house any "sub" windows.  I had to make the property not read only in order to set canedit to true when I want but otherwise I was able to implement your code exact as shown. For now I'm not marking it an answer to my entire problem but am going to vote this answer up.